# Laptop not waking from sleep after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, 22.04

Not yet entirely sure if this is root cause or something else going on. My laptop has not exhibited similar behavior before.

I typically just close laptop lead to put it sleep.

I had to install nvidia drivers as I've to use opencl. After installing the driver, my laptop just hangs when the lead is opened again. It does show some messages, but not able to copy the messages as it has not yet started.

Glanced through syslog and kern.log files, but not able to figure out what I need to look for.

After force rebooting the laptop, it does work fine, just not able to wake up.